# Different invariants per operation context

Tags: oop, domain-driven-design

How to deal with invariants which are different per operation context? Imagine you have inventory micro service and Reserve functionality. Now, that reserve functionality depends on who is performing the operation. If that's reservation for outbound delivery, then only non broken items can be reserved, if it is a reservation for internal manipulations, i.e Shift, then reservation is possible. We currently have only 1 function called Reserve. Should we implement different Reserve functions? ReserveForOutbound, ReserveForShift? Then what happens if additional rule comes in? Reservation for Repack, reservation for defects repair?

Answer (score 0):

The "it depends" is strong with one :)

Before I continue, it's worth to define the term invariant: Invariants are a type of business rules which applies across operations, at the very least across operations while the entity is in the same state (as in state of a state machine), and (quite importantly) it is often those invariants which define the immediate consistency boundary which defines the aggregate.. For more info [read here](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2020371&seqNum=2)

First thing I'd suggest is go back to your SME's/domain experts and see how they see things: is a reservation for outbound deliveries different in their eyes than the internal one? Do they refer to these two by different names? Do they have some differences later on in processing too? In this case, I'm more inclined to believe that this is a case of an error during modelling, and that you in fact have two separate entities, instead of operations on a single entity. (see Vernon's article above). Remember that an aggregates sole responsibility is to enforce these invariants, and you can create an aggregate just to enforce this one if it so happens to be that the domain experts agreee. Just push the data needed to instantiate the aggregate with the command (sync or from a message bus). Most probably if the domain experts recognise these as separate things, I would not be surprised to see that there are subsequent differences as well.

If the case is that there is really just a single entity here, I would personally definitely model it as two separate methods. This is good OO practice as well as a DDD one. This rule seems to be a significant deviation on the process and expectations, and it seems that having two methods owing that business logic (with the possibility of a shared private method) is a far better option than if-else's and data pushed into your entity to be able to make a decision, while instead this is an external concern: it's the consumer of your entity (human or system) who is asking for an internal vs external reservation.

As for your concerns about needing multiple methods, I think a discussion with your domain expert would solve this issue.

Comment: "and that you in fact have two separate entities, instead of operations on a single entity" - that would mean I won't be able to preserve invariants between different types of reservations. My Stock object is linked to Location and shows amount of pallets. If I split it in 2 (like you mentioned) and concurrently reserve for outbound and for shift from the same stock, both operations would succeed, resulting in negative quantity.

Comment: Well if you indeed do have such an invariant, then you do have a single entity, and as I said in the answer already, just model it using two methods. Again, though do speak with your domain expert to make sure about the future